# Angular-Material Layout Behavior.... sibling behavior issue

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am reading [Angular Materials Layout Container](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container). In the example of 'Layout Directive', the code exists:

```
<div layout="row">
  <div flex>First item in row</div>
  <div flex>Second item in row</div>
</div>
<div layout="column">
  <div flex>First item in column</div>
  <div flex>Second item in column</div>
</div>
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that the first `<div layout="row">` only spans 50% of the row, not the entire row. Half of the row is shared with the sibling `<div layout="column">`.

Since `<div layout="column">` is the sibling of `<div layout="row">`, it should not be in the `<div layout="row">`.

It is confusing to me that the behavior of `<div layout="column">` is as if it is a child of `<div layout="row">`, when that is not the case(it is a sibling).

Can anyone clarify this please? Is this an error?

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends on the parent of these 2 divs, when the layout of the parent is not declared, it assumes its a row:

```
<div>
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex>First item in row</div>
        <div flex>Second item in row</div>
    </div>
    <div layout="column">
        <div flex>First item in column</div>
        <div flex>Second item in column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you should change the default layout if you want a different behaviour:

```
<div layout="column">
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex>First item in row</div>
        <div flex>Second item in row</div>
    </div>
    <div layout="column">
        <div flex>First item in column</div>
        <div flex>Second item in column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```